Runtime localisation for .NET WPF Application
I'm working on localizing an old software application written in C#. It's a .NET WPF application that uses two XAML windows for the GUI. I've created a LocalizationManager class to handle translations, and the strings are stored in two .resx files (for English and German).
The translations are working correctly—I can change the language in the settings, and the selected language is saved in settings.xml, so it persists when I restart the application.
Now, I need to implement language switching at runtime. I want the language change to take effect immediately without restarting the application.
I'm not an experienced software developer, so I'm looking for a straightforward solution or best practices for this task. How can I reload the windows or trigger the necessary events to update the UI with the new language?
Thanks in advance for your help!
my Class LocalizationManager.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProgrammierstationV2.Logic.Localization
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class for managing the localisation of texts based on resource files.
    /// </summary>

    class LocalizationManager
    {
        private ResourceManager _resourceManager;
        // Property for defining and retrieving the current culture for localisation purposes
        public CultureInfo CurrentCulture { get; set; }
        static private bool eninitialized = false;
        static private CultureInfo cinfo;

        private static readonly Lazy<LocalizationManager> _instance = new Lazy<LocalizationManager>(() => new LocalizationManager());

        /// <summary>
        /// The singleton instance of LocalizationManager.
        /// </summary>
        public static LocalizationManager Instance => _instance.Value;

        /// <summary>
        /// Event that is triggered when the language is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler LanguageChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private constructor to prevent instantiation.
        /// Initialises the resource manager instance based on the name of the resource file and the assembly type.
        /// </summary>
        private LocalizationManager()
        {
            // Initialisation of the resource manager with the name of the resource file
            // and the assembly type of the LocalisationManager class>
            _resourceManager = new ResourceManager("ProgrammierstationV2.LocalizationResources.Strings", typeof(LocalizationManager).Assembly);

            // Sets the default language to English
            if (eninitialized == true)
            {
                CurrentCulture = cinfo;
            }
            else
            {
                cinfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                eninitialized = true;
                CurrentCulture = cinfo;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of supported languages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list of supported languages as culture codes.</returns>
        public List<string> GetSupportedLanguages()
        {
            return new List<string> { "en-GB", "de-DE" };
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Displays the localised text for a specific key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=‘key’>The key that references the desired localised text in the resource file.</param>
        public string DisplayLocalizedText(string key)
        {
            SetCulture(CurrentCulture);

            // Retrieve the localised text for the specified key
            string localizedText = _resourceManager.GetString(key);

            // Check whether the resource has been found
            if (localizedText == null)
            {
                // Generate an error message that the resource is missing
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: Resource with key '{key}' is missing in resource files.");
                // Returns a standard text or null
                return "Error: Missing Resource";
            }

            // Retrieve and return the localised text for the specified key
            return localizedText;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the current culture for localisation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=‘culture’>The desired culture.</param>
        public void SetCulture(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Setting the current culture and UI culture
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the current language for localisation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=‘languageCode’>The culture code of the desired language.</param>
        public void ChangeLanguage(string languageCode)
        {
            // Check whether the specified language is supported
            if (GetSupportedLanguages().Contains(languageCode))
            {
                // Create a new CultureInfo instance with the specified language code
                CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(languageCode);
                cinfo = newCulture;

                // Set the current culture for localisation
                SetCulture(newCulture);

                // Updating the CurrentCulture property
                CurrentCulture = newCulture;
            }
        }
    }
}

A colleague suggested that I could use event handlers in the MainViewModel.cs file (the file where the settings.xml is loaded when the application starts). However, I haven't been able to make much progress with that approach. Another one suggested multithreading, but right now I didn't have the time looking in to that. I'm open for different approaches as well.

Reloading is an easy option: set flag, close main window, in custom App.xaml.cs organize a loop to check flag and recreate window instead of exiting. Or simply call Process.Start(System.Environment.ProcessPath!) and shutdown the current app.

Another option is to rise event when language changes and subscribe to it everywhere. And the best option involves utilizing wpf bindings, custom markup extension and/or some code-generation (for properties returning text for current language, T4 template should help to convert resx -> cs). Then all text in UI will just changes together with language. The event is still useful to refresh generated text.

Thank you so much. For the first option, can I use the default App.xaml.cs file from my project, or do I need to create a second file ?

You need to modify the existing file of course and

I would suggest looking at my work https://github.com/SAKryukov/dotnet-solution-structure.
Unfortunately, the documentation is not yet published, mainly because CodeProject went out of business and its site works only read-only. However, the WPF globalization and localization part is pretty much self-documented.
You can use two methods of the class AdvancedApplication found in its abstract base class, AdvancedApplicationBase.Localize. All tee localization resources for each CultureInfo should be placed as satellite assemblies in the form of XAML data using the usual naming conventions for .NET resource-based globalization and localization. You can find these classes and methods here: https://github.com/SAKryukov/dotnet-solution-structure/tree/master/code/1-Agnostic/Ui/Application.
The application demonstrating the globalization and localization techniques can be found here: https://github.com/SAKryukov/dotnet-solution-structure/tree/master/code/3-Application/Demo.Localization, and it is also pretty much self documented.
Also, using this code, you can learn all the localization principles, such as dynamic loading of the resources, finding resources by CultureInfo, fallbacks, assembly metadata, all that stuff.
Anyone interested in this topic is invited to participate in the repository Discussions.
